# Como obtener e insertar id autoincremental de una tabla en otra

Tags: php, mysql

Me han pedido hacer en PHP una script que inserte valores de forma automática de un csv a la base de datos, pero aunque tengo cierta idea de PHP (poca cosa,voy aprendiendo sobre la marcha) no tengo ni idea de MySQL.

El script funciona bien, pero las respuestas tienen un campo `id_pregunta` que queda a 0 después de importarlas del csv. Así que mi pregunta es:
¿Cómo puedo extraer el id de la tabla preguntas y dárselo a las 4 respuestas insertadas en la tabla?

Me refiero a que las 4 últimas respuestas tengan el mismo `id_pregunta`.

De momento tengo esto:

```
<?php

//conexiones, conexiones everywhere
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_user = '**';
$db_pass = '**';

$database = '**';
if (!@mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass))
    die("No se pudo establecer conexión a la base de datos");

if (!@mysql_select_db($database))
    die("base de datos no existe");
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        //Aquí es donde seleccionamos nuestro csv
         $fname = $_FILES['sel_file']['name'];
         echo 'Cargando nombre del archivo: '.$fname.' <br>';
         $chk_ext = explode(".",$fname);

         if(strtolower(end($chk_ext)) == "csv")
         {
             //si es correcto, entonces damos permisos de lectura para subir
             $filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
             $handle = fopen($filename, "r");

             $data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
             $sql1 = "INSERT into preguntas(pregunta, pregunta_asturiano, juego, dificultad, url_imagen, url_video) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]','$data[4]','$data[5]')";
             mysql_query($sql1) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    $sql2 = "INSERT into respuestas(respuesta, respuesta_asturiano, correcta) values('$data[0]','$data[1]','$data[2]','$data[3]')";
                    mysql_query($sql2) or die('Error: '.mysql_error());
                }
           }
         else
         {
            //si aparece esto es posible que el archivo no tenga el formato adecuado, inclusive cuando es cvs, revisarlo para             
//ver si esta separado por " , "
             echo "Archivo invalido!";
         }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Hola, para que sea auto incrementable la tabla debes añadirle que el campo id sea autoincrementable, eso lo encontraras en la base de datos, si tienes forma de verla en PHPmyadmin

Comment: Al crear la tabla SQL deberías tener una línea en la que pongas un ID auto incrementable como primary key

create table preguntas (
    pregunta_Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    pregunta varchar(100), ...)

Luego al hacer un INSERT, ignoras la pregunta_Id que se autoincrementa ella sola

Comment: Claro,el problema es que hay varias respuestas para cada pregunta,si fuera de una en una sería más fácil, pero al ser de 4 en 4 es lo que me tiene perdido.

Comment: Yo creo que el problema principal es que no explicas bien el contexto. Un contexto *normal*  sería el siguiente: dos tablas, una de preguntas y otra de respuestas, relacionadas por `id_pregunta` que es una columna auto-incremental en la tabla preguntas. Si acabas de insertar una pregunta recuperas su id mediante `last_insert_id` y usas ese valor para insertarlo en la columna `id_pregunta` de la tabla `respuestas`... subrayando que en esa tabla la columna no es auto-incremental, sino que es del tipo `INT`. Otra cosa que se ve en tu código es que parece estás aprendiendo de tutoriales muy viejos

Comment: Ya lo he resulto,gracias. He usado la función mysql_insert_id(),la he almacenado en una variable y luego se la he dado a todas las respuestas. Solucionado en 5 min(la last_insert_id me ponía el id de la pregunta a la primera respuesta y a las demás el id de la respuesta anterior)

Answer (score 0):

Tal como has descubierto, el ID de la pregunta lo obtienes justo después de insertarla. Pero ese script sigue teniendo problemas, primero porque ocupas el conector descontinuado `mysql` y segundo porque  estás interpolando variables directamente en la consulta. Debieras susar las extensiones `mysqli` o `PDO Mysql` y hacerlo más o menos como sigue:

Hago los siguiente supuestos:

- La tabla de preguntas tiene un id autoincremental. Al insertar en ésta omites ese ID porque MySQL ya sabe que por omisión tiene que insertar el ID siguiente.
- La tabla de respuestas tiene in id autoincremental y también lo omites en la inserción.
- tu CSV tiene una pregunta y cuatro respuestas y siempre tiene esa estructura.

Entonces:

```
<?php

// Abres la conexión
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'my_usuario', 'mi_contraseña', 'mi_base');

$filename = $_FILES['sel_file']['tmp_name'];
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");

$data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");
// Preparas la inserción de la pregunta omitiendo el campo id:
$sql1 = 'INSERT into preguntas(pregunta, pregunta_asturiano, juego, dificultad, url_imagen, url_video) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)';


$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql1);
$stmt->bind_param('ssssss', $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3], $data[4], $data[5]);

$stmt->execute();
$id_pregunta = $mysqli->insert_id;
$stmt->close();
// ya tienes el $id_pregunta


// Preparas la inserción de la pregunta omitiendo el campo id_respuesta, pero sí estableciendo el id_pregunta.
$sql2 = 'INSERT into respuestas(id_pregunta, respuesta, respuesta_asturiano, correcta) values(?,?,?,?,?)';

$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($sql2);
$stmt2->bind_param(dssss, $id_pregunta, $data[0], $data[1], $data[2], $data[3]);

while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== false) {
    $stmt2->execute(); // ya se bindeó la inserción a los componentes de $data, no necesitas repetir el `prepare`
}
$stmt2->close();
```